# What pre/post season maintenance is recommended for a 2 cycle outboard motor?

Tags: gear, boats, diy, gear-care, outboard-engine

I just acquired a used Yamaha 50TLR.

I'd like to know what kind of routine maintenance I should preform to keep it in good working order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is based on what we did for ours, and may not be specific to your model (but should hold true)

- Take off the prop and grease every season
- When storing drain all fluids
- I actually find that mine works better if the first tank of the season is premium, good quality gas.
- Take out the spark plug and store separately.  I apply a tad of oil to the plug socket to keep it from corroding over the winter
- I find that working a little neatsfoot oil into the cord helps prevent dry rot and breakage.
- And needless to say, store out of the weather